# Get inside street view by location

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I want to be able to go inside establishment knowing it's location. Sometimes it works, sometimes not. I have a feeling that it is because location -> panoId works incorrectly. Let me give very specific example: http://jsfiddle.net/fubNj/28/ .

```
PanoId inside hotel: Ku1ubx_Rb5ERiER0mkgiLQ
Location: 51.689467, 5.3045419999999694
getPanoramaByLocation returns: lDpFz0F1TTVIVOG_8ufCFQ
```

I took PanoId of a hotel, and then query coordinates of that pano, then try again to get PanoId for the same coordinates, and it is different: it is on the street, not inside. And there seems to be no way to get PanoId of interior of hotel. But if you try this url: https://www.google.com/cbk?output=xml&hl=en&ll=51.689467,5.3045419999999694&radius=50&cb_client=maps_sv&v=4&it=all (which is used internally by Street View) you see that it returns the internal PanoId, but it is hackish and I want to know the official way.

The whole scenario is this: user searches for a place with Place Search API (name -> location), and is shown inside Street View (location -> internal street view).

**Edit:** For this particular location if you decrease radius it will find correct pano. But the problem now actually is that if you search for that hotel, it's location is [51.689775, 5.304426], while location of street view that corresponds to interior of hotel is at [51.689467, 5.304542]. SO the problem is that I know hotel location, but there is no way to find location/panoid of corresponding internal street view.

Comment: If I look at the [pano returned](http://jsfiddle.net/ANkMt/1/embedded/result/), it seems to be inside the hotel.  Are you just seeing a different PanoId?  Are you expecting "internal" street view to be available everywhere?

Comment: @geocodezip which pano you mean? the pano returned by getPanoramaByLocation (lDpFz0F1TTVIVOG_8ufCFQ) is just outside of the hotel.

Comment: @geocodezip I expect internal street view for establishments where there is street view. In this particular case there is a street view and I can't reach it through code. There are lots of places where getPanoramaByLocation (or just streetViewControl.setLocation) leads to internal street view.

Comment: Seems to work better if I change the radius to be less than 50 meters.  Per [the documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/streetview#StreetViewService) that makes it return the "closest" panorama (why that wouldn't be the case anyway, I don't know). http://jsfiddle.net/ANkMt/3/

Comment: @geocodezip you are right, it works, but it still doesn't answer bigger question. Check update please.

Comment: Do you have examples of cases where the smaller radius doesn't work?

Comment: @geocodezip yes I gave them. The problem that smaller radius actually work. The problem is different: location of inside street view is about 40 meters from location of the place itself (from google place search). So street's street view is indeed closer to place location. But it makes impossible to get insides pano.

Comment: @Andrey did you succeed to get it work?

Comment: @idog no, unfortunately. There is definitely a way to do this, because when you hover pegman over the area you can see panoramas with colored circles but I couldn't figure out how to get that data from code.