# Recent change in result/behavior of getPanoramaByLocation

Tags: google-maps-api-3

I've just noticed a recent change in the results returned by getPanoramaByLocation for calls with radius of 10. After identifying a place object for the streetview, in the past this code would return a custom, interior view of the space if available:

```
streetViewService.getPanoramaByLocation(place.geometry.location, 10, function(streetViewPanoramaData, status) {
```

Now, however, this call returns the same streetview as setting the radius to 50, which is to say, the standard google external streetview of the place... In this standard outside streetview, there is a navigation arrow that can be clicked to provide access to the interior custom view of the place, so it is still there. However, the objective of my site is to first display the custom interior view if one is available...

Any idea of how/why this behavior might have changed? Or if it is possible to somehow directly the getPanoramaByLocation to return a custom interior panorama by directly?

UPDATED with HTML and Javascript below

HTML

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false">     </script>
<body>
<div id="pano1" style="height:500px; width:600px;"></div>
<div id="pano1_info"></div>
<div id="pano2" style="height:500px; width:600px;"></div>
<div id="pano2_info"></div>
</body>
```

Javascript

```
var panoramaService = new google.maps.StreetViewService();
panoramaService.getPanoramaById('aZooFPuMASQAAAQIt5H7Ug', function (res, stat) {
   var loc = res.location.latLng;
   var panoramaOptions = {
       position: loc,
       pov: {
           heading: 270,
           pitch: 0
       },
       visible: true
   };
   var panorama1 = new google.maps.StreetViewPanorama(document.getElementById('pano1'), panoramaOptions);
   document.getElementById('pano1_info').innerHTML = res.location.pano;
   panorama1.setPano(res.location.pano);
   alert(loc.lat()+','+loc.lng());
});
var loc2 = new google.maps.LatLng(30.248133,-97.75047899999998);
//   var loc2 = new google.maps.LatLng(30.2481325,-97.7504791);
panoramaService.getPanoramaByLocation(
loc2,
10,
// 50,
function (streetViewPanoramaData, streetViewStatus) {
   if (streetViewStatus != "OK") {
       alert("no street view at this location I'm afraid");
   } else {
       var panoramaOptions = {
           position: loc2,
           pov: {
               heading: 270,
               pitch: 0
           },
           visible: true
       };
       var panorama2 = new google.maps.StreetViewPanorama(document.getElementById('pano2'), panoramaOptions);
       document.getElementById('pano2_info').innerHTML = streetViewPanoramaData.location.pano;
       panorama2.setPano(streetViewPanoramaData.location.pano);
       //alert(streetViewPanoramaData.location.pano);
   }
});
```

Comment: Do you know the panoID of that panorama?  Can you provide a [Minimal, Complete, Tested and Readable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates the issue?  BTW - the documentation says that for a radius of < 50, it returns the closest panorama (if I remember correctly).  Did the streetview data in that area just get updated?

Comment: I added HTML and javascript to the original post, and a sample interior panoID is included there. In the 2nd part of the code, it uses the location lat/lang from that same internal pano view with radius 10, and it can't find it. Radius 50 shows the standard street view.

Comment: Why do you need to find the pano with getPanoramaByLocation if you have the panoID?

Comment: I [see what you mean about the links that let you navigate into and out of the interior StreetView](http://jsfiddle.net/v286L1gn/1/).

Comment: My site actually starts with a place (the user searches by name). So I don't have the PanoID initially. My site does a preliminary getPanoramaByLocation on the place location with radius 10 to try to access any interior view first and display that if available (this has worked completely reliably in the past). If that fails, then I bump the radius up to 50, which displays the standard streetview instead.

Comment: I found this earlier posting the you helped with from last year that addresses this exact same issue, looks like: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16862284/get-inside-street-view-by-location. Your original example in that post no longer works? "Seems to work better if I change the radius to be less than 50 meters. Per the documentation that makes it return the "closest" panorama (why that wouldn't be the case anyway, I don't know). http://jsfiddle.net/ANkMt/3 –  geocodezip"

Comment: Interesting, you are correct. [This fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ANkMt/8/) shows the nearest "normal" panorama; and it isn't finding the interior streetview.

Comment: OK cool, so I am not imagining things! Any thoughts on how to escalate this, since it appears to be at a minimum a fundamental change in how radius works here, or perhaps even a bug/defect?

Comment: https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues